# High CPU usage on server with Apache, PHP-FPM, and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, cpu-usage, ubuntu-20.04

I have a server with 2 CPUs and 4 cores and 8gb RAM, with Ubuntu 20.04, Apache and PHP-FPM installed. Inside it, I have a WordPress multisite installation with about 150 sites.

Recently, I've been having issues with CPU usage, where 4/5 php-fpm: pool www processes are consuming all of the resources. This server shouldn't have enough traffic to occupy all those resources. Additionally, even if I restart the service or kill the processes, they continue to reappear at the exact moment I restart it.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this problem?

Thank you in advance.

I tried disabling all plugins, but it had no effect. I also don't see anything unusual in the WordPress installation when using query monitor.
I tried changing the PHP-FPM process manager from dynamic to static and ondemand, but nothing changed. I also added pm.max_requests = 500, but it didn't improve anything. I didn't find anything unusual in the logs for either Apache or PHP-FPM.